# javascript create array item in 10 interval upto 100

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, arraylist

I want to create array of object in javascript like interval manner which is dynamic like suppose interval value is 10 then it should start with 10 and end to 100

initial value = 10
end value = 100

so final array belike

```
[
 {
  "label": "10",
  "value": "10"
 },
 {
  "label": "20",
  "value": "20"
},
{
  "label": "30",
  "value": "30"
},
{
  "label": "40",
  "value": "40"
},
{
  "label": "50",
 "value": "50"
},
{
  "label": "60",
 "value": "60"
},
{
"label": "70",
"value": "70"
},
{
 "label": "80",
 "value": "80"
},
{
 "label": "90",
 "value": "90"
},
{
  "label": "100",
 "value": "100"
}
```

]

so any idea how i can make array of object as above

Comment: a for loop will do

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use normal [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop and an array [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method to achieve this.

```js
const initialValue = 10;
const endValue = 100;
const finalArray = [];

for (let n = initialValue; n <= endValue; n += 10) {
  finalArray.push({ label: n, value: n });
}

console.log(finalArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to generate the values.

We'd use a `createLabels()` function to wrap this, passing in a startValue, endValue and step.

```js
function createLabels(startValue, endValue, step) {
    const length = 1 + (endValue - startValue) / step;
    return Array.from({ length }, (v,k) => {
        const value = String(startValue + k*step);
        return { label: value, value };
    });
}

console.log(createLabels(10, 100, 10))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: 100th is missing in the array

Comment: Thanks @JijoAlexander, just updated the end value.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize your array like this :

```
[...Array(10).keys()].map(i => ({'label':10+i*10, 'value':10+i*10}))
```

If you want a more generic one :

```
const gen = (init,end,step) => 
  ([...Array(Math.ceil((end-init+1)/step)).keys()].map(i => ({
    'label':init+(i)*step, 
    'value':init+(i)*step
  })));

gen(10,100,10);
```